# Create an array with all network interfaces in bash

Tags: linux, bash, networking, ifconfig

I want to create an array in Bash which to contain all active network interfaces.

I have managed to create a for loop printing them but when I try to create the array, it just contains the last `lo` interface but not the other. This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for iface in $(ifconfig | cut -d ' ' -f1| tr ':' '\n' | awk NF)
do
           printf "$iface%s\n"
           declare -a array_test=["$iface"]
done
for i in "${array_test[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
```

And this is my output:

```
eno1
eno2
eno3
lo
[lo]
```

Also, how can I exclude the lo localhost interface from the array?

Comment: @peterh `bash` can be used for quite complex scripts (as can, e.g., `ksh` or `zsh`)....but the more complex it is, the harder it is to read, understand, and modify - and the slower it becomes (e.g. a loop around forking several programs is abysmally slow).  At that point, the time/effort cost of writing and maintaining a shell script greatly exceeds the cost of learning the basics of `awk` (or `perl`, or `python`) and rewriting it in about 1/10th the lines of codes.  If you already know one of those languages, then that point is reached much earlier.

Comment: I am writing a script to emulate network impairments using iproute and tc command. I was using this array approach to check if the user defined variable is valid. I believe writing this script in python would be a bit painful and I am also using the opportunity to learn a bit of bash.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a solution, assign the list and then add item to it:

```
#!/bin/bash

array_test=()
for iface in $(ifconfig | cut -d ' ' -f1| tr ':' '\n' | awk NF)
do
        printf "$iface\n"
        array_test+=("$iface")
done
echo ${array_test[@]}
```

If you want the output displayed one item per line:

```
for i in "${array_test[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
```

To remove localhost from output:

```
if [ "$iface" != "lo" ] 
then
    array_test+=("$iface")
fi
```

Comment: how can I exclude the ```lo``` localhost interface from the array?

Comment: added in answer and question

Comment: Actually you can do the same just by removing the last item in the array, I have found the answer in the meantime: ```unset "net_array[${#net_array[@]}-1]"```

Comment: I won't do that because I'm not sure localhost will always be in last position

Answer (score 6):

My try:

```
readarray -t interfaces < <(ip l | awk -F ":" '/^[0-9]+:/{dev=$2 ; if ( dev !~ /^ lo$/) {print $2}}')
for i in "${interfaces[@]// /}" ; do echo "$i" ; done
```

Answer (score 3):

`bash` will construct an array from any white-space delimited (spaces, tabs, newlines) list you give it.  e.g. `array=(a b c)`.  We can use command substitution (`$()`) to generate such a white-space delimited list.  For example:

```
$ ifaces=( $(ip addr list | awk -F': ' '/^[0-9]/ {print $2}') )
```

and now print out the array we just created:

```
$ declare -p ifaces
declare -a ifaces=([0]="lo" [1]="eth0" [2]="eth1" [3]="br1" [4]="br0" [5]="ppp0")
```

To exclude `lo`:

```
$ ifaces=( $(ip addr list | awk -F': ' '/^[0-9]/ && $2 != "lo" {print $2}') )
$ declare -p ifaces
declare -a ifaces=([0]="eth0" [1]="eth1" [2]="br1" [3]="br0" [4]="ppp0")
```

If you really want to use `ifconfig` rather than `ip`, try this:

```
ifaces=( $(ifconfig | awk -F':'  '/^[^ ]*: / && $1 != "lo" {print $1}') )
```

Answer (score 3):

`ifconfig` only outputs the interfaces that are up.

On Linux, you can get a list of interfaces in the `/sys/class/net` directory. So, with `zsh`, you can do:

```
interfaces=(/sys/class/net/*(DN:t))
```

To exclude `lo`:

```
set -o extendedglob
interfaces=(/sys/class/net/^lo(DN:t))
```

For only the `up` ones, you could do:

```
interfaces=(/sys/class/net/*(DNe{'[[ $(<$REPLY/operstate) = up ]]'}:t)
```

or, assuming the default value of `$IFS`.

```
interfaces=($(ip -br link | LC_ALL=C awk '$2 == "UP" {print $1}'))
```

On my system at least the status for `lo` is UNKNOWN so would be excluded.

That would also work with `bash` provided interface names don't contain wildcard characters. In recent versions of Linux, IIRC, interface names are guaranteed not to contain space tab and newline characters (the default `$IFS`), so those would not cause problem. Other Unicode blanks are allowed though, hence the LC_ALL=C which should guarantee that `awk` won't split on those.

Answer (score 1):

If you have '-j' support for `ip` (json output) then use the *excellent* `jq` utility;

```
# ip -j addr show | jq -r .[].ifname
lo
eth0
eth1
tunl0
gre0
gretap0
erspan0
ip_vti0
ip6_vti0
sit0
ip6tnl0
ip6gre0
dummy0
kube-ipvs0
cbr0
vethfbcab624
```

(example from a kubernetes node)

Comment: Typo; shall be "ip -j link show"